# How to loop through a JSON file using Python with nested lists and dictionaries

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to loop through a JSON file using Python and return the name of the object and associated modules for it.

Right now I can basically get the output I want hardcoding the indexes. However, this obviously isn't the right way to do it (the JSON file can vary in length).

Whenever I try to use a loop, I get errors like:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

My JSON file looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "gaming_companies",
    "columns": [{
            "name": "publisher",
            "type": "string",
            "cleansing": ["clean_string"]
        },
        {
            "name": "genre",
            "type": "string",
            "cleansing": ["match_genre", "clean_string"]
        },
        {
            "name": "sales",
            "type": "int",
            "cleansing": []
        }
    ]
}
```

My Python code which is 'working' looks like:

```py
import json as js

def cleansing(games_json):
      print (games_json['columns'][0]['name'] + " - cleansing:")
      [print(i) for i in games_json['columns'][0]['cleansing'] ]
      print (games_json['columns'][1]['name'] + " - cleansing:")
      [print(i) for i in games_json['columns'][1]['cleansing'] ]
      print (games_json['columns'][2]['name'] + " - cleansing:")
      [print(i) for i in games_json['columns'][2]['cleansing'] ]

with open(r'C:\Desktop\gamefolder\jsonfiles\games.json') as input_json:
  games_json = js.load(input_json)
  cleansing(games_json)
```

The output I'm trying to return is:

```
publisher
cleansing:
clean_string

genre
cleansing:
match_genre
clean_string

sales 
cleansing:
```

My attempt to loop through them like this:

```py
      for x in games_json:
          for y in games_json['columns'][x]:
              print (y)
```

Results in:

```py
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

games_json shows as a Dict.

Columns shows as a list of dictionaries.

Each object's cleansing attribute shows as a list.

I think this is where my problem is, but I'm not able to get over the hurdle.

Comment: Hint: print `x` at the beginning of each iteration of the outer for loop and consider how that affects the inner loop.

Comment: Iterating over a dict like `for k in _dict:` will return the keys of the dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your attempt is using an iterator as a string.

The `x` in `for y in games_json['columns'][x]:` is an iterator object and not the strings `['name', 'cleansing']`.

You can learn more about python iterators [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_iterators.asp)

---

As for the case - you might want to iterate over the `columns` as a separate list.

This code should work

```
for item in f["columns"]:
    print(item["name"])
    print("cleansing:")
    print(item["cleansing"])
```

Output-

```
publisher
cleansing:
['clean_string']
genre
cleansing:
['match_genre', 'clean_string']
sales
cleansing:
[]
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be one of working solutions as you want to iterate array's elements.

```
import json 

for x in games_json['columns']:
    print(x)
    print(x['name'])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = """{
    "name": "gaming_companies",
    "columns": [{
            "name": "publisher",
            "type": "string",
            "cleansing": ["clean_string"]
        },
        {
            "name": "genre",
            "type": "string",
            "cleansing": ["match_genre", "clean_string"]
        },
        {
            "name": "sales",
            "type": "int",
            "cleansing": []
        }
    ]
}"""
x = json.loads(x)
for i in x['columns']:
    print(i['name'])
    print("cleansing:")
    for j in i["cleansing"]:
        print(j)
    print('\n')
```

Output

```
publisher
cleansing:
clean_string


genre
cleansing:
match_genre
clean_string


sales
cleansing:
```

---

```
with open(r'C:\Desktop\gamefolder\jsonfiles\games.json') as input_json:
    games_json = js.load(input_json)
    for i in games_json['columns']:
        print(i['name'])
        print("cleansing:")
        for j in i["cleansing"]:
            print(j)
        print('\n')
```